# I am trying to write FASTA files but the write function is not working, even if I add the .close() at the end of it, any suggestions?

Tags: python

I added my code below. The output is always an empty file.

```
Fasta_1 = ">ABC123\n ATCGTACGATCGATCGATCGCTAGACGTATCG"
Fasta_2 = ">DEF456\n actgatcgacgatcgatcgatcgacgact"
Fasta_3 = ">JIH789\n ACTGAC-ACTGT--ACTGTA----CATGTG"


output = open("sequence.fasta", "w")
output.write = (Fasta_1 + '\n' + Fasta_2 + '\n' + Fasta_3)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is **output.write** is not a property, it is function. So, it should be called this way:

```
Fasta_1 = ">ABC123\n ATCGTACGATCGATCGATCGCTAGACGTATCG"
Fasta_2 = ">DEF456\n actgatcgacgatcgatcgatcgacgact"
Fasta_3 = ">JIH789\n ACTGAC-ACTGT--ACTGTA----CATGTG"


output = open("sequence.fasta", "w")
output.write(Fasta_1 + '\n' + Fasta_2 + '\n' + Fasta_3) # < !!!!
output.close()
```